# pygame.mixer can't play more than 8 notes

Tags: audio, pygame, mixer

I'm trying to create a small program that will read notes that I write in a text file and play it as piano music.

I'm using pygame and using the mixer to play `.aiff` sound files.  Everything works fine except that it will not play more than 8 notes. Does anyone know anything about this? I've tried with different files and notes and it always stops after the 8th note, but it will play that note in its entirety.

Here's some of the code:

```
lines = f.readlines()

while lines[x] != '':
    line = lines[x]
    readingframe = line[b:b+4]
    for t in times:
        if t in readingframe:
            c = line.index(t,b)
            note = line[b:c]
            sound = mixer.Sound('C:/Python27/piano/' + note +'.aiff')
            sound.play()
            time.sleep(timeCorrespondence[t])
            b = c+1
```

And this is one of the sample music I was using to test (O Canada):

```
a4hc5qc5if4hg4qa4qbb4qc5qdb5qg4wz
```

The 'z' is used because the reading frame I set was 4 and some pieces end on a white key which only has three letters (abc) where a is the note, b indicates position, and c indicates length.

Comment: Including some code to your question can help people to better understand the problem. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ok sorry. Will edit right away

Comment: ok, first it looks like your frame is catching 4 chars (`line[b:b+4]`) and not 3 like you described.

Comment: For example, 'ab4q' is the A flat of the fourth octave played as a quarter note and a4q is A of the fourth octave played as a quarter note. So sometimes I need it to read 4 chars and sometimes 3 chars. By using a reading frame of 4, it will catch both cases and since the duration of notes is always at least 3 chars away from eachother, the reading frame will never catch more than one duration.

Comment: now is clear, your code is reading only `n` notes per line where `n` is the size of `times`. (`for t in times`)

Answer (score 1):

This little fix should resolve your problem:

```
lines = f.readlines()

while lines[x] != '':
    line = lines[x]
    readingframe = line[b:b+4]

    while b < len(readingframe):
        for t in times:
            if t in readingframe:
                c = line.index(t,b)
                note = line[b:c]
                maxTime = timeCorrespondence[t] * 1000
                sound = mixer.Sound('C:/Python27/piano/' + note +'.aiff')
                sound.play(maxtime=maxTime)
                b = c+1
                break
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hmm, when I use your code, it only plays 2 notes. I'm wondering why but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @Tony can you verify if the program is reading all the notes, adding `print note` before get the aiff file.

Comment: yep, it's definitely reading all of the notes just fine.

    Please enter file name'let it all out'
c5
bb4
a4
f5
c5
a4
bb4
f5
f5
g5
f5
c5
c5
bb4
bb4
a4
bb4
c5
c5
e4

Comment: @Tony I edited my answer, now it should work, the only condition is the duration of the sound has to be higher than the duration of a whole note. It's possible that you experiment latency problems, if that is the case then try to load all the sounds before starting the process of parsing the notes.

Comment: It could be, I checked out the documentation for the pygame mixer again and realized it's default is 8 channels. It might be that the 8 notes are taking up all the channels. I'm gonna take a look at your answer now

Answer (score 0):

Pygame has 8 channels by default.

> The mixer defaults to supporting 8 simultaneous soundfiles. You can change the number of available sound channels at any time with the set_num_channels() function.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.get_busy